# PageSetup.Zoom removes pagebreaks and shrinks export

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a report that needs to be reformatted and then saved as a PDF using a macro.  I'm a complete newbie to VBA, but I've got it doing everything I need, but when I add the last bit of formatting

```
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

all the page breaks disappear and the report shrinks to a inch and a half wide on the page. If I remove those two lines, it prints the same range over 3 landscape pages.  I feel like I'm missing a nugget of VBA wisdom.  Here's what I've done so far:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suggested Stock")
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 6 To LastRow Step 1
   If Cells(iRow, 2) = "Subtotal" Then
       ws.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ws.Rows(iRow).Offset(1, 0)
   End If
Next iRow

Range("6:13").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("D:AS").ColumnWidth = 4
Range("D7:AS7").Orientation = xlUpward
Range("D6:AS6").WrapText = True
Range("6:6").RowHeight = 30
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
    .PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows("6:7").Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1

End With

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\Julie Sager\Documents\TM Reports\Suggested Stock.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some stray cell way off to the right somewhere? if you debug print `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address` what is the result?

Comment: Thanks! It is pulling a lot (about 16,000) of extra columns.  But there's no visible data out there on the spreadsheet and clearing columns doesn't seem to help.  Do I resolve this by setting a print area?

Comment: Finally found the issue: Don't use FitToPagesWide without also setting FitToPagesTall.  Thanks @cybernetic.nomad for your help!